# Shopify /cart/update.js not working as expected

Tags: jquery, ajax, api, shopify, liquid

I have attached the code please check:
If I passed the data to the AJAX function hardcoded like "{ updates: {40066070315190: 0, 40067491528886: 0, 40094075945142: 0} }", then it is working fine but when I tried to make it dynamic and set the variant IDs and quantity through the loop then it is not updating the data but still going to the success function.

What's the issue any guesses?

```
  var formData = { updates: {} };
  jQuery.getJSON('/cart.js', function(thisCart, textStatus) { // Get cart items
    $.each(thisCart.items, function(cartIndex, cartElement) {
      if(~cartElement.title.indexOf('Build your own box')) {
        formData.updates[parseInt(cartElement.variant_id)] = 0;
      }
    });
  });
  jQuery.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '/cart/update.js',
    //         data: { updates: {40066070315190: 0, 40067491528886: 0, 40094075945142: 0} },
    data: formData,
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data) {
      console.log('success', data);
    },
    error: function (request, status, error) {
      alert(request.responseText);
    }
  });
```

Also attaching the console.log output for the references
[CLICK TO SEE THE CONSOLE.LOG OUTPUT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZAbOg.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check, you are getting data in formData before calling **/cart/update.js** API. As you are calling two API's you will need to wait till 1st API process and provide formData.

Comment: oh Perfect!!!

I just tried timeout for 3 seconds to test as you suggested and it works fine here is the code:

setTimeout(function(){ ajax function.... }, 3000);

Can you please let me know how it could be better?

Comment: Id' say you need a Promise https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise

Comment: I was able to achieve this using .then:
jQuery.getJSON('/cart.js', function(thisCart, textStatus) {
        $.each(thisCart.items, function(cartIndex, cartElement) {
          if(~cartElement.title.indexOf('Build your own box')) {
            formData.updates[parseInt(cartElement.variant_id)] = 0;
          }
        });
      }).done(function() {
         //ajax function
      });